# Repassar dados de uma lista de uma planilha 1 para outra lista da planilha 2 sendo que ordenado pelo maior para menor de uma coluna numérica

Tags: microsoft-excel, classificação

Na planilha 1 tenho uma lista de ocorrência que tem várias colunas de `C` a `AI`, estou querendo repassar os dados dessa lista da coluna `C6:C25` e `AI6:AI25` para planilha 2, para as colunas `D6:D25` e `E6:E25`, respectivamente, de forma ordenada do maior para menor e evitando células vazias, pois preciso construir um gráfico de pareto pelos dados da planilha 2.

Eu encontrei uma fórmula

```
=SEERRO(ÍNDICE('Folha de Verificação'!C$6:C$25;MENOR(SE(ÉCÉL.VAZIA('Folha de
Verificação'!$C$6:$C$25);"";CORRESP('Folha de
Verificação'!C$6:C$25;'Folha de
Verificação'!C$6:C$25;0));LIN(1:1)));"ERRO"),
```

porém ela dando erro, neste exemplo https://br.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20140619133050AAyGyIR

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você apertou Ctrl + Shift + Enter na célula da fórmula? Pois se trata de uma fórmula array. Se apertar somente o Enter ela não vai funcionar corretamente.

Comment: Deu certo, mas o número 7 foi pra E26 e não E7. E outra coisa, como eu trago de forma ordenado do maior para menor?